# invoke lua script from python --lupa

Tags: python, lua, lupa

This is my lua script

```
local r = {}

for _, m in pairs(ARGV) do
  r[#r+1] = redis.call('SISMEMBER', KEYS[1], m)
end

return r
```

I have a set data type (redis) where I have added some numbers and using lua script to check if a given list of numbers exist in the redis set

I've tested this from command line  , verified is the key and the arguments are the numbers , output is as expected, boolean values for each number

```
$ redis-cli --eval is_contact.lua   verified  , 113232293287 132233325 12344553334
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 0
3) (integer) 0
```

Im trying to invoke this from python , I have tried using lupa

```
import lupa
lu = lupa.LuaRuntime(unpack_returned_tuples=True)
```

How do I invoke the lua script and pass arguments ? `lu.eval` ?

Comment: use `subprocess.call` https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: what is the advantage of using subprocess vs lupa?

Comment: It was another method of running your lua script as you have done in cmd, OR you may try this clean and well explained documentation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa

Comment: Im familiar with subprocess , thank you but I was trying to achieve trough lupa , i have a reason and Im not sure if I want waste your time explaining everything here

Comment: Go ahead with the documentation I linked above, it explains all the important things you may need.

Comment: I have seen the documentation before posting a question here . Doesn't really answer what Im looking for but I guess I will have to give it another reading